# Can we use jdbc driver to read from mariaDB and SAP-HANA using data Fusion

Tags: google-cloud-data-fusion

I want to read data from MariaDB and SAP-HANA and load in BigQuery using Data Fusion. Is it possible to read using jdbc driver?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently you can use the Database plugin with MariaDB and SAP HANA drivers to load data into BigQuery using Cloud Data Fusion. Here is some documentation on how to use JDBC drivers with Cloud Data Fusion - https://cloud.google.com/data-fusion/docs/how-to/using-jdbc-drivers.

By EOY, Cloud Data Fusion will also have specific plugins for MariaDB and SAP HANA which will still need the drivers, but which will significantly improve the configuration process.